# Objective-C + JSON Parse objectForKey for Google Places API

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, json, parsing

I've got this:

```
    //request stuff
NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sydney"];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%@&sensor=true&key=mykeynotyours!",searchString];

NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:(requestURL)];

//response
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSDictionary *locationResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

NSLog(@"%@",locationResults);
```

Which is spitting out a few results, the first of which is the one I want, but I can't get the lat and lng like I could with other API's by saying:

```
NSString *stringLatitude = [locationResults objectForKey:@"lat"];
```

I suspect that key it's looking for is a subset of the "results" key which I don't know how to tell it :-(

Results:

```
    2013-04-12 18:47:49.784 Test[26984:c07] {
"html_attributions" =     (
);
results =     (
            {
        "formatted_address" = "Sydney NSW, Australia";
        geometry =             {
            location =                 {
                lat = "-33.8674869";
                lng = "151.2069902";
            };
            viewport =                 {
                northeast =                     {
                    lat = "-33.4245981";
                    lng = "151.3426361";
                };
                southwest =                     {
                    lat = "-34.1692489";
                    lng = "150.502229";
                };
            };
        };
```

Appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can access geometry lat and lang using following code

```
NSString *stringLatitude = [[[[[locationResults objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lat"];
NSString *stringLongitude = [[[[[locationResults objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lng"];
```

Comment: it should be working, though let me check again if any mistake..!

Comment: It's throwing an error on NSDictionary not having index values (locationResults is an NSDictionary object)

Comment: check out new answer..@NessyString

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 NSString *stringLatitude = [[[[[locationResults objectForKey:@"results" ]objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"lat"];
 NSString *stringLongitude = [[[[[locationResults objectForKey:@"results" ]objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"lng"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using iOS 7? Drop this into your project: https://github.com/gdyer/GDGooglePlaces

Then... just use this `- (id)initWithPlaceCategory:(NSString *)_category urlStub:(NSString *)_stub lat:(float)\ _lat andLon:(float)_lon;`

Mapping, parsing, viewing, directions, sharing, and more is all handled for you.